# Eloquent ORM filter the content after slash character

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying fetch the data in the form like `app/img.png`. When i use Eloquent ORM, the result will get `app` (the content after slash will filter). However, I tried to use Query Builder, and it works! The result will show `app/img.png`. I have googled it, but nothing found. How should fix the problem if I want to use Eloquent ORM?

-- edit --

**Eloquent**

```
$images = Image::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
                 ->select('name', 'URL')
                 ->get();
```

**QB**

```
$images = \DB::table('images')
                 ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
                 ->select('name', 'URL')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: post your query builder code

Comment: Can you post the code you're working with currently?

Comment: thanks for both of two, I have updated the code

Comment: Can you `dd($images)` after replacing `->get()` with `toSql()` ?

Comment: Please post the data in the `images` table and the result of `dd($request->get('q'))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of answers. After several of weeks, I found out I have set `$primaryKey = 'URL'` in the model, but I did not set `$keyType = 'string'`. After setting `$keyType = 'string'`, and everything works!

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this:

```
$images = Image::select('name', 'URL')
          ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->get('q') . '%')
          ->get();
```

Comment: Tested on Laravel 5.8, using the `select` before or after the `where` clause doesn't change anything. In my tests, it worked for both cases